# Rotate an object around in a circle while facing the correct direction

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

Im currently using THREE.js to build a program where a car travels around in a circle. I am able to get the car to travel in a circle correctly, however the car is always facing the same direction and doesn't turn with the curve. I somewhat understand that I need to get the tangent of the car at its location to the circle and that will somehow tell me the direction the car needs to look in (rotation of Y axis), but I don't understand how to do this in THREE.js or in general how to use this tangent to change the direction.

Kind of like this, but 3D:

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
  function car() {

      // Code to add camera

      // make a ground plane
      let groundBox = new T.BoxGeometry(10, 0.1, 10);
      let groundMesh = new T.Mesh(groundBox,new T.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x88b888, roughness: 0.9 }));
      groundMesh.position.y = -0.05;
      scene.add(groundMesh);

      let car = new T.Group();

      let width = 1;
      let height = 1;
      let widthSegments = 5;
      let heightSegments = 5;
      let depth = 1;
      let depthSegments = 5;
      let bodyGeometry = new T.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth, widthSegments, heightSegments, depthSegments);
      let bodyMaterial = new T.MeshStandardMaterial({color: "red"});
      let bodyMesh = new T.Mesh(bodyGeometry, bodyMaterial);
      car.add(bodyMesh);

      scene.add(car);
      car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
      car.position.y = 2;

  }

  function animate() {
      // move in a circle
      let theta = performance.now() / 1000;
      let x = 3 * Math.cos(theta);
      let z = 3 * Math.sin(theta);

      car.position.x = x;
      car.position.z = z;

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  animate();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share the code that is _not_ working?

Comment: There are a 100 ways to do this. Without more code **in the question itself** or more description we can't tell what solution you need. If all you want is that exact look above, make an `Object3D` (`const ob = new THREE.Object3D(); scene.add(ob);`), make the car a child of it (`ob.add(carMesh);`). Offset the car (`carMesh.position.x = 2;`), rotate the object (`ob.rotation.y = time;`). You might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-scenegraph.html) useful

Comment: Just updated with my code so far